# Does GitHub Action install the same packages each time?

Tags: github-actions

The [GitHub actions documentation](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/using-python-with-github-actions#running-tests-with-tox) recommends to put in each workflow, an installation of all the required packages, such as flake8, pytest, etc. Does this mean that, whenever I push a change to my repository, GitHub installs all these packages anew? This seems very wasteful: a lot of energy is wasted each time. Why do they need to reinstall all packages again and again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, GitHub actions does not cache any files and will have to fetch them each time.

However, you can cache the packages with the cache action: https://github.com/actions/cache

An example for pip:

```
- uses: actions/cache@v1
  with:
    path: ~/.cache/pip
    key: ${{ runner.os }}-pip-${{ hashFiles('**/requirements.txt') }}
    restore-keys: |
      ${{ runner.os }}-pip-
```

The cached files must not exceed 400 MB. Unused caches will expire after 1 week.

My guess is that these are powered by shared Azure DevOps agents and each agent instance is cleaned up after a build job.

Comment: So, is the answer yes or no?

Comment: The answer is, it depends on what you configure it to do. If you don't use a cache action, then no, it does not reuse files that it previously retrieved. By using the cache action, the files you specify are placed in a global cache, as long as it does not exceed 400 MB per cache and no more than 2 GB per repository.

Comment: You should add that to your post then